# How to isolate conditional panels from other conditional panels when axis scroll involves one panel and not the other?

Tags: r, shiny, carousel

In the below reproducible code, two main conditional panels are presented: "Stratification" and "DnL balances". The first presents a smaller data table where no scroll bars are automatically introduced, and the 2nd presents a larger data table where scroll bars are introduced.

The scroll bars in one conditional panel appear to be affecting the other conditional panel. I have tried addressing with `style = "display: none;"` (based on a related post yesterday), flagged with ### in this reproducible code, but it leaves the 2nd conditional panel without the glide/well panel across the top unless the user adjusts the size of the window, however minutely. Yesterday's posted solution worked fine, but that code didn't render a data table. When introducing a data table and resulting scroll bars, the issue manifests.

Is there a way to resolve this? May be a hack, but even a tiny automated adjustment to the size of the window may help?

The images at the bottom better explain the issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyglide)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$style(".glide-controls { position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 14px; width: 160px; }"), 
    titlePanel("Hello"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(selectInput("selectData", h5(strong("Select data to view:")),choices = list("Stratification","DnL balances"),selected = "Stratification")),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Private data", value = 1,
            div(style = "margin-top:10px"),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectData == 'Stratification'",
              fluidRow(
                column(12,
                 glide(
                   custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()), 
                   screen(
                     wellPanel(
                       radioButtons(
                         inputId = 'groupStrats',
                         label = NULL,
                         choiceNames = c('Calendar period','MOB'),
                         choiceValues = c('Period','MOB'),
                         selected = 'Period',
                         inline = TRUE), 
                     style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                     ), 
                   screen(
                     wellPanel(
                       radioButtons(
                         inputId = 'stratsView',
                         label = NULL,
                         choices = list("Table view" = 1,"Plot view" = 2),
                         selected = 1,
                         inline = TRUE), 
                     style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                   ) 
                 ) 
                ) 
              ),
              fluidRow(tableOutput("mtCarsPart")),
            
              conditionalPanel(condition = "input.stratsView == 2", style = "display: none;", fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("stratPlot"))))
            ),
            ### comment out "style..." in line below to see the issue ###       
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectData == 'DnL balances'", style = "display: none;",
              fluidRow(
                column(12,
                  glide(
                    custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()),
                    screen(
                      wellPanel(
                         radioButtons(
                           inputId = 'groupBal',
                           label = NULL,
                           choiceNames = c('Calendar period','MOB'),
                           choiceValues = c('Period','MOB'),
                           selected = 'Period',
                           inline = TRUE),
                      style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;")
                    ),
                    screen(
                      wellPanel(
                        radioButtons(
                          inputId = 'balView',
                          label = NULL,
                          choices = list("Table view" = 1,"Plot view" = 2),
                          selected = 1,
                          inline = TRUE), 
                        style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                    )
                  )
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(tableOutput("mtCarsFull"))
            ) 
          ), id = "tabselected"  
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtCarsFull <- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$mtCarsPart <- renderTable(mtcars[1:10,1:3])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use a base-shiny table? I think we could work around the issue via `library(DT)`

Comment: Thank you ismirsehregal. DT table is what I usually use, I only used a base-shiny table in this case for sake of example simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The dev-version is already fixed:
`remotes::install_github("juba/shinyglide")` should resolve the issue.

**Initial answer:**

Regarding shinyglide's behaviour I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/juba/shinyglide/issues/30).

Using `library(DT)` you could avoid the long output which leads to the vertical scrollbar:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyglide)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$style(".glide-controls { position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 14px; width: 160px; }"), 
    titlePanel("Hello"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(selectInput("selectData", h5(strong("Select data to view:")), choices = list("Stratification","DnL balances"), selected = "Stratification")),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Private data", value = 1,
                   div(style = "margin-top:10px"),
                   fluidRow(
                     column(12,
                            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectData == 'Stratification'",
                                             glide(
                                               custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()),
                                               shinyglide::screen(
                                                 wellPanel(
                                                   radioButtons(
                                                     inputId = 'groupStrats',
                                                     label = NULL,
                                                     choiceNames = c('Calendar period','MOB'),
                                                     choiceValues = c('Period','MOB'),
                                                     selected = 'Period',
                                                     inline = TRUE), 
                                                   style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                                               ), 
                                               shinyglide::screen(
                                                 wellPanel(
                                                   radioButtons(
                                                     inputId = 'stratsView',
                                                     label = NULL,
                                                     choices = list("Table view" = 1,"Plot view" = 2),
                                                     selected = 1,
                                                     inline = TRUE), 
                                                   style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                                               ) 
                                             ),
                                             DTOutput("mtCarsPart"),
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.stratsView == 2", style = "display: none;", fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("stratPlot"))))
                            ),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectData == 'DnL balances'",
                                                glide(
                                                  custom_controls = div(class = "glide-controls", glideControls()),
                                                  shinyglide::screen(
                                                    wellPanel(
                                                      radioButtons(
                                                        inputId = 'groupBal',
                                                        label = NULL,
                                                        choiceNames = c('Calendar period','MOB'),
                                                        choiceValues = c('Period','MOB'),
                                                        selected = 'Period',
                                                        inline = TRUE),
                                                      style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;")
                                                  ),
                                                  shinyglide::screen(
                                                    wellPanel(
                                                      radioButtons(
                                                        inputId = 'balView',
                                                        label = NULL,
                                                        choices = list("Table view" = 1,"Plot view" = 2),
                                                        selected = 1,
                                                        inline = TRUE), 
                                                      style = "padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 0px;") 
                                                  )
                                                ),
                                      DTOutput("mtCarsFull")
                            )
                     )
                   )
          ), id = "tabselected"  
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtCarsFull <- renderDT(mtcars)
  output$mtCarsPart <- renderDT(mtcars[1:10,1:3])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```